# JavaScript EU cookie law banner not removing

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I've been trying to add a EU cookie policy banner to my website. The javascript code below inserts the banner (once I add a small bit of styling) but when I click on the "x" to close the banner and hopefully hide it for future visits, nothing happens. The banner doesn't disappear.

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working? Javascript is not my strong point!

```
//Cookie banner

var dropCookie = true;                      // false disables the Cookie, allowing you to style the banner
var cookieDuration = 14;                    // Number of days before the cookie expires, and the banner reappears
var cookieName = 'complianceCookie';        // Name of our cookie
var cookieValue = 'on';                     // Value of cookie

function createDiv(){
    var bodytag = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('id','cookie-law');
    div.innerHTML = '<p>Our website uses cookies. By continuing we assume your permission to deploy cookies, as detailed in our <a href="/privacy-cookies-policy/" rel="nofollow" title="Privacy &amp; Cookies Policy">privacy and cookies policy</a>. <a class="close-cookie-banner" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="removeMe()"><span>X</span></a></p>';    
 // Be advised the Close Banner 'X' link requires jQuery

    // bodytag.appendChild(div); // Adds the Cookie Law Banner just before the closing </body> tag
    // or
    bodytag.insertBefore(div,bodytag.firstChild); // Adds the Cookie Law Banner just after the opening <body> tag

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className+=' cookiebanner'; //Adds a class tothe <body> tag when the banner is visible

    createCookie(window.cookieName,window.cookieValue, window.cookieDuration); // Create the cookie
}


function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000)); 
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString(); 
    }
    else var expires = "";
    if(window.dropCookie) { 
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/"; 
    }
}

function checkCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)===' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

window.onload = function(){
    if(checkCookie(window.cookieName) !== window.cookieValue){
        createDiv(); 
    }
};

function removeMe(){
    var element = document.getElementById('cookie-law');
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you do not use JS a lot, I would recommend you use an existing solution: https://cookie-script.com

Comment: Hi Stephan, this is an existing solution, found here https://www.creare.co.uk/js-eu-cookie-law-banner. Javascript is one of the languages I'm trying to learn and I figure I'll never get anywhere if I don't practice :-)

Comment: O wow. The code does not exactly suggest someone with JS knowledge wrote it...

Comment: Ah, ok, what makes you say that? It did look a little complicated to do something that simple but I don't really know enough to do more than work out what it's saying

Comment: There's really too much going on in all conventions that are broken to get into that for a question like this. However, I have solved your issue in the answer below :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `removeMe` is `undefined` in the current scope of the `onclick` handler. To fix this, you should replace this line `function removeMe() {` with `window.removeMe = function removeMe() {`.

Live example (with formatted code): https://jsfiddle.net/xnhpzto8/1/

Comment: That's why we're all on this website ;-)